# How to link together React child and parent components when instantiating them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, `TopBarItem` and `Menu`, which are nested and have the functionality "if the menu is open, the top bar should not show the tooltip". I'd like to wire them together like this:

```
<TopBarItem tooltip="Settings">
  <Menu onOpen={parent.tooltipOff} onClose={parent.tooltipOn}>…</Menu>
</TopBarItem>
```

Is this possible in JSX / React? Happy to drop down to JS, as well, but would prefer to keep it JSX if possible.

Another option (from deleted answer) is to wrap both components in a third grandparent which maintains the `tooltipEnabled` state and pass it down to `TopBarItem` via a property. While that's perfectly acceptable, I'd prefer to toggle the state in `TopBarItem` directly rather than via a grandparent, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with the implementation suggested by the formerly deleted answer. Will accept more concise solutions if anyone knows of any.

```
export class TopbarMenuItem extends Component {
  state: {
    tooltipEnabled: bool
  }
  tooltipOn: () => null;
  tooltipOff: () => null;

  constructor(props: Object) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tooltipEnabled: true
    }
    this.tooltipOn = this.tooltipOn.bind(this);
    this.tooltipOff = this.tooltipOff.bind(this);
  }

  tooltipOff() {
    this.setState({tooltipEnabled: false});
  }

  tooltipOn() {
    this.setState({tooltipEnabled: true});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TopbarItem tooltip={this.state.tooltipEnabled ? this.props.tooltip : ''}>
        <Menu onOpen={this.tooltipOff} onClose={this.tooltipOn}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Menu>
      </TopbarItem>
    );
  }
}
```